# How do I write a filter program in C?

Tags: c, filter

Since UNIX has all those wonderful filter-like programs (such as `grep`, `sed`, `tr` and so forth), what's the easiest way to write one of those in standard C?

By filter, I mean a program which reads standard input, performs some manipulation of the data, and then writes it to standard output. This is useful in constructing pipelines of commands, with each performing some additional manipulation of the data, such as:

```
grep xyzzy input.file | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | sed 's/plugh/PLUGH/g'
```

(each of the `|` pipe symbols connects the standard output of the previous command to the standard input of the next, hence the pipeline metaphor).

Let's say I needed one that converted all uppercase characters to lowercase. And, yes, I realise this *particular* problem can be solved with the UNIX:

```
tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'
```

but that's just an *example.*

What I'm actually after is the simplest standard C source code to do such a filter.

Comment: Am I missing something?  April 1 was a couple days ago...

Comment: For all the tools you mentioned, you can easily find the source code. Why not have a look at that to find out how they're implemented ?

Comment: @Michael, no, it came up when I was answering another question, and I realised there was no question covering this. As per guidelines (SO meant for all level of users and answering your own questions), I thought I'd put it up. Obviously, _I_ know how to do it, but I won't rep-whore, instead letting someone else answer (unless they don't in a couiple of day in which case, I'll rep-whore to the max :-)

Comment: @Sander, I don't need to look at source code, I know how to do it. However, since the question wasn't on SO, I put it here. The idea is to to make SO the place to go for programming-related questions.

Comment: In any case, I've maxed out my rep for the day, so I think I'll go have a coffee :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: I see. I agree it's a legit question.  Better than several I've seen the past few days. That it came from someone like you threw me a bit...

Comment: Do you mean the simplest source code that yields comparable functionality as the standard tools you mentioned?

Comment: @paxdiablo : I'd think my point is still valid. The code out there is pretty good, tried and tested, and complete, as opposed to the quick, specific, limited samples you're likely to get here. The easiest way to write one of those tools in standard C ? Look at how others have already done just that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `getline` as described by @hroptatyr, but you can do something a lot simpler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(tolower(c));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that someone should really explain the key point: a filter is a program that reads `stdin` does something (which could include doing nothing, such as `cat`) to the data and writes the transformed data to `stdout`.  Of course, many filters do much more than that, such as read/write to files other than `stdin`/`stdout` if directed by options. But I think that's the core concept of a filter.

Answer (score 5):

A "filter" program is simply a program which reads from the standard input stream ([`stdin`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdin#Standard_input_.28stdin.29)) and writes to the standard output stream ([`stdout`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdin#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)). Before writing the read data, the data is usually transformed in some way (if you don't preform any transformation or filtering, you basically wrote an `cat` program which just prints out whatever is given to it). The power of filter program comes from the fact that they don't dictate where their input comes from or where the output is going to. Instead, it's up to the caller of the program to provide the input/output channels.

The core of a filter program could look something like this (you can use this as a template for your own filter programs):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int filter( FILE *input, FILE *output );

int main( void )
{
    const int retval = filter( stdin, stdout );
    fflush( stdout );
    return retval;
}
```

That's it. The actual work is done by a `filter` function which performs the transformation you desire. For instance, here's a simple program which reads the characters from the input file, turns them to lowercase, and then prints them to the output file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> /* for tolower */

int filter( FILE *input, FILE *output )
{
    while ( !feof( input ) ) {
        if ( ferror( input ) ) {
            return 1;
        }
        fputc( tolower( fgetc( input ) ), output );
    }
    return 0;
}

int main( void )
{
    const int retval = filter( stdin, stdout );
    fflush( stdout );
    return retval;
}
```

If you compile and run this program, it'll simply sit there and patiently wait for data to read from the standard input file `stdin`. This file is usually bound to the console, which means that you have to enter some data by hand. However, command shells implement a feature called pipes which allow you to pipe the output of one command to the input of another. This allows composing multiple programs into a [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) to form powerful commands.

Here's how we could use our filter program (assuming you called the resulting binary `lower`):

```
$ echo Hello | lower
hello
$
```

Since our filter program doesn't define where the data to be read is coming from, we can combine it with all kinds of programs producing output on `stdout`. For instance, here's how you can get a whole file as lowercase (you can use `type` on Windows machines instead):

```
$ cat myfile.txt
Hello, World!
This is a simple test.

$ cat myfile.txt | lower
hello, world!
this is a simple test.

$
```

Comment: The `fflush(stdout);` seems to be useless: "If the `main`
function returns to its original caller, [...] all open files are
closed (hence all output streams are flushed) before program termination." (ISO/IEC 9899:1999, 7.9.13, §5).

Comment: @undur_gongor: To be hoenst, I agree; I didn't have the `fflush` call in my first version. However, when trying the program on a Windows XP box, I noticed that I didn't see any output. Explicitely flushing `stdout` helped - I didn't bother checking any further (I have less-than-stellar experiences with the C API on Windows).

Comment: Then your C implementation is broken or the program is being killed sometime after main but before actually flushing the stdout buffer.  Normally if stdout is a terminal it's line-buffered so you don't see output until you output a newline (or flush / exit).

Answer (score 3):

In pseudo-code:

```
do
  line = read(stdin);
  filter(line);
  print(line);
until no_more_lines
```

In real code:

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0U;
ssize_t n;

while ((n = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) >= 0) {
        /* LINE is of length N, filter it */
        filter(line, n);
        /* print it */
        fputs(line, stdout);
}
free(line);
```

and `filter()` looks like:

```
static void filter(char *line, size_t length)
{
        while ((*line++ = tolower(*line)));
}
```

Edit: Don't forget to define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L` or `_XOPEN_SOURCE >= 700`.
And don't forget to include `stdio.h` for `getline()` and `ctype.h` for `tolower()`.

Comment: @paxdiablo A function probably defined elsewhere.

Comment: "Standard C has functions to do this, but they aren't very safe: [...] So the GNU library provides the nonstandard getline function" http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html

Comment: I updated the answer to point people where/how to get `getline()`

Answer (score -5):

```
L1:
 mov dx,081
 mov cx,1
 mov bx,0
 mov ax,03f00
 int 021
 cmp ax,0
 je L2
 cmp b[081],'a'
 jb L3
 cmp b[081],'z'
 ja L3
 sub b[081],020
L3:
 mov dx,081
 mov cx,1
 mov bx,1
 mov ax,04000
 int 021
 jmp L1
L2:
 mov ax,04c00
 int 021

; Example in A86 Assembler see eji.com for A86/D86
```

Comment: Can you explain this more?